# Compress GraphQL Query?

Tags: python, graphql

I am looking for a *standard* way of compressing a GraphQL query/response to send it through MQTT.

I am thinking of something that can:

- Remove extra spaces
- Remove extra new lines (`\n`, `\r`);
- Compress the message (zlib?)

I took a look to Graphene and other GraphQL modules for Python, but I have not found what I am looking for yet.

Is there a terminology that I am missing or is this something that I should not do?

Comment: Thankfully this is probably no different than compressing any JSON over AJAX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to compress a GraphQL query in Python I could come up with is:

```py
import shlex

query_with_strings = """
        query someQuery    {
                Field(
                 search: "string with   spaces"
                ) {
                        foo
                }
        }
"""


def compress_graphql(q):
    """Compress a GraphQL query by removing unnecessary whitespace.

    >>> compress_graphql(query_with_strings)
    u'query someQuery { Field( search: "string with   spaces" ) { foo } }'
    """
    return u' '.join(shlex.split(q, posix=False))
```

This assumes that all queries are already `unicode` (Python 2) or `str` (Python 3) objects.

Running the doctest will pass.